# Taking the next element of a list with numbers and names

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a long list like this:

```
some_list=["PointID:","1","'Y':", "1.134","'X':","1.223", "'Z':","1.0","PointID","2", "'Y':","1.4", "'X':","1.75","'Z':","1.0"]
```

I need to extract the coordinates and put them in txt file, which will be use as input for CAD Software drawing.
My solution is:

```
some_list=["PointID:","1","'Y':", "1.134","'X':","1.2223", "'Z':","1.0","PointID","2", "'Y':","1.4", "'X':","1.75","'Z':","1.0"]
for index, element in enumerate(some_list): 
    if element == "'X':" or element == "'Y':" or element == "'Z':":
        print(index, next(element))

The output is: 
2 'Y':
4 'X':
6 'Z':
10 'Y':
12 'X':
14 'Z':
```

But actually, I am interested in the coordinates 1.134, 1.223 etc.
Something like this:

```
Y: 1.134 
X: 1.223
```

etc
I try print(element+1) and print(next(element)) which of course do not work because. Next works with iterators, not iterable.
Any suggestions on how I could extrude the coordinates from the list? I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: You can create an iterator from a list with `my_iterator = iter(my_list)`

Comment: And please, format the code in your question as code, not plain text.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and also your attempt and current issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the expected output, but here is a generator that yields the X/Y/Z and the following points:

```
some_list=["PointID:","1","'Y':", "1.134","'X':","1.223", "'Z':","1.0","PointID","2", "'Y':","1.4", "'X':","1.75","'Z':","1.0"]

def get_coord(l):
    it = iter(l)
    for item in it:
        if item in ["'X':", "'Y':", "'Z':"]:
            item = item.replace("'", '')
            yield f"{item} {next(it, None)}"

print('\n'.join(get_coord(some_list)))
```

output:

```
Y: 1.134
X: 1.223
Z: 1.0
Y: 1.4
X: 1.75
Z: 1.0
```